# Haskell, not sure how to

Tags: haskell

In one Haskell guide we are ask to calculate the weight of a tree based on this conditions:

- From 0 to 3 meters it weighs 300 Kg/meter.
- Over 3 it weighs 200 Kg/meter.

This is what I tried. It's close but doesn't solve it completely:

```
weightTree high = 900 + (high - 3) * 200
```

Comment: You are assuming the tree is at least 3 meters high. What if `high` is less than 3?

Comment: When asking for debugging help, you should explain what you did, what result you hoped for, and what result you got. If you know *why* you did not get the right result, you should explain that. If you made any attempts to fix the bug, you should explain what they were and what went wrong with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a few days i came out with a better way to solve this. Thanks to everyone who reply me, here i leave you what i end up doing (maybe it can help someone else):

```
weightTree height = (min height 3) * 300 + ((max height 3) - 3) * 200
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Control.Monad (sequence_)

weightTree :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a
weightTree height = lowerWeight + upperWeight
  where lowerWeight = 300 * lowerHeight
        upperWeight = 200 * upperHeight
        lowerHeight = (max 0 . min 3) height
        upperHeight = max 0 (height - 3)                

main :: IO ()
main = sequence_ $ test <$> [-1..5]
  where test h = putStrLn $ concat [ "Height "
                                   , show h
                                   , ", weight "
                                   , show (weightTree h)
                                   ]
```

Output:

```
Height -1, weight 0
Height 0, weight 0
Height 1, weight 300
Height 2, weight 600
Height 3, weight 900
Height 4, weight 1100
Height 5, weight 1300
```

Comment: I see how the break down can be educational, but I find guards more newbie friendly personally:  `weightTree h | h < 0 = 0 ; h <= 3 = h * 300 ; | otherwise = 300*3 + 200*(h-3)`.

Comment: Hm. I've never been a fan of jumping to case analysis before it's necessary.

Comment: Case analysis is pretty readable here, especially since it mirrors the problem description exactly.

Comment: I disagree; the problem description doesn't directly state that the weight of a tree taller than 3 meters is equal to 300*3 + 200*(h-3). You did some math beforehand to derive that formula, rather than transcribing the problem.